# Wordpress Site taking me to malicious site on first visit

Tags: wordpress, redirect

My UAT wordpress site is taking to a 3rd party site while opening first time on mobile. After a refresh it is working fine, no redirection.

I have tried to disable all the plugins but the the issue still persists. Is there any way to overcome it?

NOTE :: The redirection is happening just the first time, on the second time onwards the site is working fine.

Comment: Your WordPress and/or theme files are hacked. Re-install the WordPress or restore from backup. Review security measures afterwards

Comment: can you share the site url?. from what you are saying it looks like your site may be hacked, use wordfence plugin to scan your site. it will show the infected files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am unable to share the URL for security reason. I m installing and started a scan of my website. Hope it helps. If not im updating you soon.! @plsankar